# After installing ubuntu 18.04, the laptop keep powering off and on over and over just after dell logo no Ubuntu screen

Tags: 18.04, dell, shutdown

I have a Dell G3 3779 with dual hard drives. I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 previously and it was working fine then suddenly it stopped working after I changed some display settings for multiple screens. After that I am trying to install again but when I do it install completely then says reboot computer and After rebooting my laptop starts then after reaching dell logo there is a black screen then shuts down then again starts and it continues. I have to forcefully shut it down by pressing down the power button. There is no hardware issue and I have not changed any kind of bios settings. what is the solution to this?? Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance 
I have tried 18.04, 19.04, even 20.04 same thing happens.
This is the link of the image of gparted:

[image: gparted]

Comment: Since software doesn't morph (i.e. changes itself) some event must have taken place (such as an upgrade) to make your device stop working. Use a live image to check if your disk is still alive. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1246621/edit) your question to fill in the missing pieces...

Comment: How to check it and what is that I don't understand?

Comment: I have added the link you asked @user68186